# What is the proper way to bring power to this pump?

Tags: wiring, pump

I purchased [this pump](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001FAA5Y) to transfer water from a holding tank in a self remodeled travel trailer up to the sink. The pump is an "on demand" style where it will pump pressure in the water line up against a closed faucet. A pressure switch on the pump cuts off the power when the pressure limit is reached. When the faucet is opened the pressure drops and the pump starts up to deliver water flow to the sink.

The motor on the pump operates on 120VAC. As you can see the wires to the pump are discrete wires including the hot wire path through the pressure switch.

[image: pump side view]

[image: pump end view]

My question is about the proper way to wire up and deliver AC power to this type of unit?

Comment: Given the fact there is no self contained junction box, I would terminate the leads in a male plug and plug it in.  It's not perfect, but the pump manufacturer precluded your ability by not including a self j-box.

Comment: I agree but it will need to be in a enclosed space that is dry.

Comment: Should have mentioned, plug into GFCI receptacle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wire on the pump is not rated to be exposed or cord connected.

You will need to mount the pump inside an enclosure such as a Hoffman box or equivalent.

[image]

Then you can terminate a raceway or cable to the enclosure and the wiring will be protected inside.

Since RV's are covered by the National Electrical Code, this will satisfy the NEC.

Good luck!

Comment: Most rv's have a space for a pump that doesn't require an additional box but the connections need to be made in a box if not fully enclosed as most units are.

Comment: For added safety, try to adjust the wires from the pump so there's a low spot between the pump and whatever junction point where the wires connect to the power feed.  This is done so any possible water drip won't short main power at the connection.

Comment: I considered this exactly prior to my comment to the question.  The problem is fluid hoses that have to also enter the enclosure.  This seems to be a definite purpose pump, designed for a specific split enclosure.

Comment: You could find some grommets for the holes the plumbing enters through to protect the hoses.